# What is the optimal strategy for player two, given a matrix game $\begin{pmatrix}3&1&4&0\\1&2&0&5\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: proof-verification, game-theory

This problem is part the book I'm using in my game theory course. My work-through is as follows:

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&1&4&0\\1&2&0&5\end{pmatrix}$.
>
> Note how for $P_2$, strategy $(1,0,0,0)$ is strictly dominated by $q=(0,0,\frac{39}{50},\frac{11}{50})$ since $$Aq = (4\cdot\frac{39}{50},5\cdot\frac{11}{50}) = (3\frac{3}{25}, 5\frac1{10})>(3,1)=Ae^1.$$
>   Similarly, strategy $e^2$ is strictly dominated by $q=(0,0,\frac12,\frac12$), since $Aq=(2,2.5)>(1,2)=Ae^2$.
>
> **Here I speed up  a bit because it's not as relevant**
>
> To solve the remaining game $\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\0&5\end{pmatrix}$, suppose $P_1$'s strategy $p_1=(p,1-p)$. Then we find $4p=5-5p$, so $p=5/9$ with a game value of $20/9$. Solving for $q$ then gives us that $P_2$'s strategy $q=(0,0,5/9,4/9)$.

The problem is, that the book says this is false and that $P_2$'s optimal strategy is $(0,4/5,1/5,0)$, which according to my solution is impossible since $e^2$ is a strictly dominated strategy.

Where exactly am I going wrong here?

Comment: What is your "real question"? Do you want to find all the Nash equilibria of the game? It is not clear what are you asking...

Comment: I believe thats what the book means, yeah. But the term Nash equilibrium hasn't come up yet, just optimal strategy. Perhaps the term minimax will help you narrow down what the goal is.